# In Objective-C, can you use class extension within a category?

Tags: objective-c

Can you use class extension within a category?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe a class extension *is* a category. So the question would be, can you add a category to a category

Comment: You mean can you write private category right??

Comment: Be more explicit. What do you mean by "use"?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Meaning within your category, you create a class extension in the .m file.